# Javascript bookmarklet for toggling webpage editing on/off?

Tags: javascript, web, bookmarklet

I once saw a JavaScript bookmarklet on the internet, but I lost it.

The bookmarklet does not specifically enable/disable the page editability, but **it does toggle the editability,** meaning that pressing the exact same bookmark turns editing on (enables) if it is currently off (disabled), and vice versa.

What was the bookmarklet script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best way to turn it off easily would be to just create another bookmarklet, except change 'true' to 'false.'...or you could use this convinient toggleable bookmarklet

[Drag this into bookmark bar](http://javascript:(function(e,n,o,t)%7Bo=e.body,t=%22true%22==o[n],o[n]=t%3F%22false%22:%22true%22,e.designMode=t%3F%22off%22:%22on%22%7D)(document,%22contentEditable%22))

source: https://gist.github.com/jameswyse/b5b9f42bf38e7c09262cb37ea44ce626

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks. Hopefully, I jumpstarted your reputation, i Penguin. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for a bookmarklet which toggles editing on and off:

```
javascript:if(document.body.contentEditable === 'true'){document.body.contentEditable = 'false';}else if (document.body.contentEditable === 'false'){document.body.contentEditable === 'true'}void 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the code, but it dosen't toggle of and on. If you want to turn it off just reload the page.

javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0

Comment: “but it dosen't toggle of and on” – And that's the problem. But I have already found the solution.